# My array isn't recognized as array when it contains only one value

Tags: php, arrays

In my code, I fill an array using this line in a loop :

```
 $_SESSION['my_array'][] = $some_value;
```

After each execution of this line, I do some check (doesn't matter here for which purpose) using the `function in_array()`. However, at the first iteration it says :

```
« in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array ».
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can we see the code where you are doing in_array()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the array (before you fill it with values) like this:

```
$_SESSION['my_array']=array();
```

This way you can be sure that it is array, even when it would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning or accesing it wrongly

Use this

```
$_SESSION['my_array'] = $some_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the `in_array` check, you can cast the second item to an array, so if it's empty then it will pass an empty array. This way you don't ever set anything to the session when you don't need to (which could trip you up later on)

e.g.,

```
if (in_array('foo', (array)$_SESSION['my_array'])) {
  // do something
}
```